# Service fabric - How to deploy docker container from local repository?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-service-fabric, windows-server-2016, docker-container

I have setup docker host in my local system running Windows Server 2016 and pushed docker container images using docker-compose. I would like to host these containers in my local service fabric cluster.

- Is it mandatory to push these docker container images to some public docker container repositories like docker hub or azure container repository? So that service fabric guest application can be configured to download them during deployment.
- Can I also configure service fabric guest application to connect to local docker repository to download container images?

Comment: Your question is confusing, so I will ask more to clarify. 


Did you make a custom docker image correct?


Do you want to download this image to another location right?


Do you have a private repository and the correct access to push a docker image to that repository?


You no need necessary push your custom image to the public repository.

Comment: I got my question self answered. Thanks for your comment. Anyways, I will clarify your follow up questions. All I had to do is create docker containers using docker-compose and store them in local docker instance running in Windows Server 2016 and publish them in Local Service Fabric Cluster running the same machine. Previously publish was failing due to conflict with docker container tag. When executing docker-compose in debug mode in visual studio, it was overriding tag. I got it resolved by executing in "Release" mode without debugger.